# Shape of librosa.feature.melspectrogram

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, spectrogram, librosa

I'm trying to understand the output of `librosa.feature.melspectrogram`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from librosa.feature import melspectrogram
>>>
>>>
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(128), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 1)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(900), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 2)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(500), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 1)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(512), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 2)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(511), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 1)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(1023), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 2)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(1024), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 3)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(2055), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 5)
>>> melspectrogram(np.random.randn(2047), n_mels=128).shape
(128, 4)
```

What determines the second value of its shape? The first one is clear, it's `n_mels`, but from the [docs](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/LibROSA.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) I can't understand where the second one comes from.

Comment: It's the length of the signal in *frames* (not samples), depending on window and hop length. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733609/942774) for more details.

Comment: yes, makes sense, thanks, it's `1 + len(y) // hop_length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the length of the signal in *frames* (not samples), depending on window and hop length. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733609/942774).

Concretely: `1 + len(y) // hop_length`