# Relation between hop_length, win_length, frame_length, n_fft, no.of frames

Tags: python, librosa, mfcc

I am working with `mfcc` features in Python via `librosa`:

```py
mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y,sr=sr,n_mfcc=12,n_fft=320,hop_length=320,htk=True)
```

Here, I took audio signal of 1s duration which gave me `len(y) = 16000`, hence I took `sr = 16000`. I calculated the number of frames using `n,n_f=mfccs.shape`, where `n` is the number of `mfcc` coefficients (12) and `n_f` is the number of frames.

I got `n_f = 51`, however, I don't understand how 51 is possible. What is the relation between the number of frames, hop_length, n_fft and win_length? I cannot find an explanation of the relation(s).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733609/942774) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for this answer. So far, I am setting the values of hop_length and n_mfcc like in the example below to get a squared mfcc matrix of shape (n,n).
Thats all I know about it. I have not much experience on it.
The documentation is at https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html

This link contains some good informations:
https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/595
:

```
[...]
lengthAudioSignal=len(audioSignal)    
dimensionsOfMfccMatrix = 10 #(you choose, according to your application)
n=dimensionsOfMfccMatrix
sr=16000
    
hop_length = lengthAudioSignal// (dimensionsOfMfccMatrix - 1)  # To get a 
                                                      # square mfccMatrix

n_fft= ? (I am not sure of this)

melfcc = np.abs(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audioSignal,                                    
          n_fft=n_fft,
          win_length=n_fft,
          hop_length=hop_length,
          sr=sr, 
          n_mfcc = dimensionsOfMfccMatrix,
          fmin=200,
          fmax=sr // 2
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the calculation of the mfcc using left-handed window frames and centered window frames.

The formula for left-aligned frames in your variable names is

*n_f* = 1 + floor (len(*y*) - *n_fft)* / *hop_length*.

The formula for centered frames (librosa default) is

*n_f* = 1 + floor (len(*y*) + 2 * *n_fft*/2 - *n_fft*) / *hop_length* = 1 + floor (len(*y*)) / *hop_length*,

because two times *n_fft*/2 zeros are padded to the original data - at each end of y a number of *n_fft*/2 zeros.

The second equation gives in your case
*n_f* = 1 + floor (16000/320) = **51**.

That's the numer you supplied in your question.

The used equations are given at:
https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/595#issuecomment-313116650